# Have graph recovery problems been studied?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, graph-theory, constraints

I’m interested in the minimum number of edges required to specify a graph $G$ uniquely when $G$ is known to satisfy some property.

For example, if we know that $G$ is a cycle graph on $n > 3$ vertices, we need to specify at least $n-2$ edges to fully determine $G$. That is, if we are given $n-2$ edges $(2,3), (3,4),\ldots, (n-1,n)$ then the only way $G$ is a cycle graph is if we also have the edges $(1,2)$ and $(n,1)$. Note that ‘up to isomorphism’ is not sufficient, the vertices of $G$ are labelled so we want to recover it exactly.

Another example could be: if $G$ is a tree on $n$ vertices such that every vertex has degree at most 3, what is the minimum number of edges one needs to specify to uniquely identify $G$?

Have such problems been studied before? I assume this could have something to do with efficient storage of graphs, although I’m not really sure where to look.

Comment: Another example would be complete bipartite graphs.  Having a path of even  length between two nodes would determine they are in the same part, and odd path in different parts. The necessary condition for a graph $H$ with a complete bipartite extension to have a unique one would require it to be connected .

Comment: But there could be a lot of edges possible for the complete bipartite example. If $n=2m+1$ nodes, there could be $m^2$ edges and the odd one would still not have any edge, so a mere count condition is fairly weak.

Comment: I’m interested in finding a minimal edge set that suffices. So in the complete bipartite case on n vertices, it would just require n-1 edges and you can’t do any better. Was wondering if there are any other cool graph families for which finding the minimal edge set is an interesting problem.

Comment: Even a path, much less a more general tree, requires all the edges to be given to be uniquely identified.

Comment: Ah, the word "recovery" gave me the impression of "What is $m$ so that if I have $m$ edges, I know the graph?" The minimal number of edges needed is a different animal altogether. Now this reminds me of the questions about smallest Sudoku puzzles. https://www.technologyreview.com/2012/01/06/188520/mathematicians-solve-minimum-sudoku-problem/

Comment: That is interesting, thank you!